# Get location redirect url from jquery ajax statuscode 401

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-codes, http-status-code-401

I currently have the below code and need to get the `location` parameter to redirect to.  How do I grab it with the statusCode setup?

**Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: (def.data ? (def.convertToJson ? JSON.stringify(def.data) : def.data) : ''),
                type: def.type,
                dataType: def.dataType,
                cache: def.cache,
                contentType: def.contentType,
                statusCode: {
 401: function (response) {
                        debugger
                        window.location = GET LOCATION URL FROM RESPONSE
                    }}
```

**Response Parameter**

```
response.getAllResponseHeaders()
```

> 'access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,
> Accept\r\naccess-control-allow-origin: *\r\ncache-control:
> private\r\ncontent-length: 58\r\ncontent-type: text/html\r\ndate: Mon,
> 06 Dec 2021 16:51:23 GMT\r\nlocation:
> https://localhost:44360/store?storeorganizationid=24917#/login?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44360%2fstore%2faccount%3fstoreorganizationid%3d24917%26_%3d1638809474810\r\nserver:
> Microsoft-IIS/10.0\r\nx-aspnet-version:
> 4.0.30319\r\nx-aspnetmvc-version: 5.2\r\nx-exposure-server: EastUS2\r\nx-exposure-sport: Basketball\r\nx-powered-by:
> ASP.NET\r\nx-sourcefiles:
> =?UTF-8?B?RjpcTXkgV2Vic1xCYXNrZXRiYWxsVG91cm5hbWVudHNcTmV3UmVnaXN0cmF0aW9uXFdlYnNpdGVzXFRvdXJuYW1lbnRzXHN0b3JlXGFjY291bnQ=?=\r\nx-ua-compatible:
> IE=Edge,chrome=1\r\n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get that value:

```
response.split('location:')[1].split("\r\n")[0];
```

```js
let response = 'access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept\r\naccess-control-allow-origin: *\r\ncache-control: private\r\ncontent-length: 58\r\ncontent-type: text/html\r\ndate: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 16:51:23 GMT\r\nlocation: https://localhost:44360/store?storeorganizationid=24917#/login?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44360%2fstore%2faccount%3fstoreorganizationid%3d24917%26_%3d1638809474810\r\nserver: Microsoft-IIS/10.0\r\nx-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319\r\nx-aspnetmvc-version: 5.2\r\nx-exposure-server: EastUS2\r\nx-exposure-sport: Basketball\r\nx-powered-by: ASP.NET\r\nx-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?RjpcTXkgV2Vic1xCYXNrZXRiYWxsVG91cm5hbWVudHNcTmV3UmVnaXN0cmF0aW9uXFdlYnNpdGVzXFRvdXJuYW1lbnRzXHN0b3JlXGFjY291bnQ=?=\r\nx-ua-compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1\r\n'

let loc = response.split('location:')[1].split("\r\n")[0];
console.log(loc);
```